# how to count only selected options in dropdown list using javascript

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

How to Implement custom validation in multiselect list in contact form 7 wordpress?

Comment: is the select input is multi select?

Comment: yes, how can I validate this? I want minimum two options should be select.

Comment: why do you want jquery validation as you can set server side validation in contact from 7 and this from useing ajax submission.

Comment: i have tried something like http://jsfiddle.net/N6YK8/8/
But i want both dropdown shoul be work different.

Comment: change menu-1 to classtype

Comment: I've put the answer check this and let me know if you found any issue

Comment: and dont forget to chnage menu-1 to classtype in your form shortcode and save the form again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_select', 'custom_select_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function custom_select_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( 'classtype-1' == $tag->name ) {
        if($_POST['menu-123'] =='Nursery to III'){
        $selected_options = isset( $_POST['classtype-1'] ) ?  $_POST['classtype-1'] : '';
        if(count($selected_options) < 2){
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Select Atleast 2 options." );
        }
        }
    }

    if ( 'classtype-2' == $tag->name ) {
        if($_POST['menu-123'] =='IV to VIII'){
            $selected_options = isset( $_POST['classtype-2'] ) ?  $_POST['classtype-2'] : '';
        if(count($selected_options) < 2){
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Select Atleast 2 options." );
        }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: i've changed the answer replace it

Comment: Sorry, I can't.

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: Yes, it's working....but it has one more issue...If I select Nursery to III and  it's 1 or more activity (by mistake) then I choose IV to VIII and it's activity...then I am receiving in mail all Selected activities from both ( Nursery to III AND IV to VIII)...Can we solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in your functions.php file to validate the select input

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_select', 'custom_select_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
 
function custom_select_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( 'classtype' == $tag->name ) {
        $selected_options = isset( $_POST['classtype'] ) ?  $_POST['classtype'] : '';
        if(count($selected_option) < 2){
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Select Atleast 2 options." );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: you are useing menu-2 in your shortcode use "classtype" instead of menu-2

Comment: Hey, it is working. But still, it has one issue. I explain.
there are two options in Student Grade. On each selection different Select Activities Dropdown. 
Can you please check again form?

Comment: yes i know think now you can manage it by applying a little logic. if dont please let me know i will help you

Comment: i have put the another answer and chnage your menu-1 and menu-2 to classtype-1 and classstype-2

Comment: have you gave the negative vote for my answer? please give upvote for the answers

Comment: classtype-1 and classstype-2 also not working. Please try to fill form. How to solve it